# sqlsrv_connect attempt doesn't succeed or fail

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, xampp, sqlsrv

I'm attempting to connect to a MS SQL Server via PHP7 sqlsrv driver.
It seems like when my browser tries to execute:

```php
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server=$serverName;Database=mydb", $uname, $pass);
```

or

```php
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

it just hangs. No success or failure echo/die messages are received. Instead, the wheel in my browser keeps spinning and the status message is "waiting for localhost". It also doesn't seem to ever timeout. I've waited 10+ minutes and the connection never fails/succeeds.

Full code (I've tried procedural and PDO methods):

```php
<?php

//
$serverName = "myserver\myinstance"; //serverName\instanceName
$uname = "myuser";
$pass = "mypass";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"mydb", "UID"=>$uname, "PWD"=>$pass);

/*Procedural sqlsrv method

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
     die("DONE");
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
*/

/*PDO sqlsrv method*/  
try {  
    $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server=$serverName;Database=mydb", $uname, $pass);  
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    die("success!");
} catch(PDOException $e) {   
    die($e->getMessage());   
}

?>
```

Setup details and other information:

- I'm using XAMPP.
- Windows 7 x64
- PHP 7.0.9
- I'm trying to connect to an instance of Microsoft SQL Server version 10.50.6220.0 on a Windows NT machine
- I need to authorize via SQL Server Authentication -- not Windows Authorization
- I'm able to successfully connect to the database using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and other tools (FME Workbench)
- The server is remote, but is accepting remote connections (as verified with SSMS)

I previously had issues with "undefined function sqlsrv_connect()" until I installed

```
php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
```

and

```
php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
```

into my php/ext folder and updated the php.ini. When I open phpinfo I see sqlsrv in both the "Registered PHP Streams" and "PDO drivers" fields.

What should I do to get a successful connection or get more information about why my connection attempt does not succeed/fail?

EDIT:
I've switched to XAMPP (PHP 5.6.24). I am able to connect to the SQL Server via CLI now, but NOT able to connect via PHP-CGI (through the browser/served by Apache HTTPD). I've verified again through php_info() that the sqlsrv and PDO extensions have been successfully loaded. I'm going through the differences between PHP-CGI and PHP CLI now to see what might be causing the issue.

EDIT:
I'm using IIS now instead of Apache and am able to connect via sqlsrv without issues. Not really a solution, but a way around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try like that :

```
try {
    $db = new PDO( 'sqlsrv:server=serwer_name;Database=database_name', 'user', 'password'); 
} catch (PDOException $e) {            
    echo $e->getMessage();   
}
```